# Colloborative real-time editing

Tags: spring-boot, edit

Our requirement is to build a collaborative real-time record edit feature in our application. Tech stack is Java with Spring boot (at the back end) and Mac os application at the front end.

Any thoughts on the approach to implementing the same would be appreciated.

Comment: Real time edit of what?

Comment: Edited the question - We are looking at a feature where each user when opens the record for editing should also be able to see a list of other users who have opened the same record for edit..